About Catalan Number: How many ways are there of queuing so that everyone gets ticket?
Problem:

In a queue for £1 cinema tickets, there are m people with a £1 coin
and n people with a £2 coin. There is no extra change at the cinema.
To buy a ticket, those with £2 coin will have to get their change. How
many ways are there of queuing so that everyone gets ticket?

To make it possible, m≥n has to be satisfied.
So there are two methods to solve this in my mind. To make it easier to present, I will put apart the permutation things temporally.
One is to let possible overall number subtract the number of situation that won't meet the conditions, which is $C_{m+n}^{m} - C_{m+n}^{m+1}$.
The other looks more direct, which first select n from m people with a £1 coin to make pair with those with a £2 coin, and n vs n make it a Cn(nth Catalan Number). To sum up, the results is $C_{m}^{n}*Cn=C_{m}^{n}*C_{2n}^{n}/(n+1)$.
But unfortunately, that 2 results is not equal.
My question is: which one is right, why and why not?

Taking people to be indistinguishable,the first one is correct, it is a known method using Catalan numbers/Dyck words, as here
The second one has a fundamental error at start inasmuch as pairing the two denominations (with a £1 in the leading pair, of course) will certainly avoid shortage, but pairing is not the only way to avoid shortage, e.g. all the £1 holders could be at the head of the queue !
I think the simplest solution is using the relaxed Bertrand'sBallot Theorem where $m\geq n$ is allowed, and the probability of not coming to a stop is $\Large\frac{m+1-n}{m+1}$
so the full solution is $\Large\frac{m+1-n}{m+1}\binom{m+n}{m}$

Thanks for your reply. Now I could get the first method. But why "pairing the two denominations (with a £1 in the leading pair, of course) is sufficient but not necessary to avoid shortage"? Could you explain that further?

@VictorLi: What I meant is that there are many more possibilities, eg all £1 holders could be at the head of the queue as an extreme case, so they don't necessarily have to be in pairs. I will amend the wording in the answer, too, for greater clarity.

You should specify in the OP that the people are indistinguishable apart from the coins they hold.
The second one cannot be correct.
Let $m=3,n=2$.
$C_{m}^{m+n} - C_{m+1}^{m+n}=5$
$C_{n}^{m}*Cn=6$
and all possible cases are
12121,12112,11221,11212,11122.
In the second method: For those chosen $n$ people with £$1$, if they happened to appear next to a not chosen person with £$1$ in a specific queue, it makes the same queue as if the other person was chosen instead.
I did not find mistakes in the first method. It follows the method as in calculating Catalan numbers.

Sure, the people are indistinguishable, so we could put aside permutations things. About the second method, I mean the chosen n person with £1 to be those eventually contribute change for those with £2.
